# Excel Macro to move Column data

Tags: vba, excel

I have been told that macros is probably the only way I am going to be able resolve this issue and I am not at all familiar with vba or excel macros. Thanks in advance for any help..

I have a situation where I am receiving data from one system like this in spreadsheet

```
1   E111    Project Location    Department  Company    
2   E222    Project Location    Department  Company    
3   E333    Project Location    Department  Company
```

And I need to display it like this with one row for each Organization Type along with row identifier to be loaded into another system.

```
1   Project    
1   Location    
1   Dept    
2   Project    
2   Location    
2   Dept    
3   Project    
3   Location    
3   Dept
```

Comment: But what is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to transpose data as per your logic, try this:

```
Sub TransposeColumns()

    Dim srcwsh As Worksheet, dstwsh As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

    Set srcwsh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set dstwsh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    'define initial rows
    i = 2 'source worksheet
    j = 2 'destination worksheet
    Do While srcwsh.Range("A" & i) <> ""
        srcwsh.Range("A" & i).Copy dstwsh.Range("A" & j & ":A" & j + 2)
        srcwsh.Range("C" & i & ":E" & i).Copy
        dstwsh.Range("B" & j).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, False, True
        j = j + 3
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    Set dstwsh = Nothing
    Set srcwsh = Nothing

End Sub
```

You have to change the code to your needs.

Comment: What is the point of setting your worksheets to nothing at the end? Does this give some benefit?

Comment: @BerticusMaximus, this is one of the best practices and it's used to "release resources".

Comment: Worked liked a charm - exactly what I needed - thanks so much

Comment: @GeneLynch, you're very welcome and thank you. Cheers, Maciej